# ngx dropzone - change accepted files format with a condition

Tags: angular, typescript, file, types, format

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to narrow down the accepted files format in ngx-dropzone for some condition.
For default I want ngx-dropzone to accept all types of files, but if user clicks an image button (which fires showFileSelector()) I want user to be able to select only image files.
Is there any way I can achieve that?
Passing a variable for accept attribute is not working.
The dropzone itself (no accept attribute so by default accept all):

```
<div
  ngx-dropzone
  class="controls"
  [maxFileSize]="maxFileSize"
  #drop
  [disableClick]="true"
  (change)="receiveFileToSend($event)"
>
```

But when user clicks this image, I want him to be able only to choose image files:

```
<img
    class="mr-2 cursor-pointer"
    src="../../../assets/icons/addImage.svg"
    (click)="drop.showFileSelector()"
    alt=""
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dropzone) I can see that ngx-dropzone has an input property called `accept` that can be used to determine which file types are allowed. You can bind a variable to this accept property and set it dynamically to whatever file type you want to allow.
E.g.:

HTML

```
...
   <ngx-dropzone (change)="onSelect($event)" [accept]="accept">
...
```

Typescript

```
accept = '*';
...
onImageClick() {
  this.accept = 'image/*';
}
```

Stackblitz of working application can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xqzxec?file=src/app/app.component.ts